# getting error with bc - (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Tags: command-line, bc

I am doing:

```
echo "scale=2; sqrt( (-9.522 - -9.522)**2 + (-17.145 - -17.145)**2 + (-2.689 - -2.689)**2 )" | bc
```

and I am getting:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: While I don't know how to achieve this with BASH, you can try GNU Octave for doing calculations, if that was what you primarily wanted to do. You can also try the [command line version](https://github.com/sharkdp/insect/releases) of [Insect](https://insect.sh/), a powerful calculator and unit converter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exponentiation operator in `bc` is `^` not `**`. From `man bc`:

> ```
>    expr ^ expr
>           The result of the expression is the value of the first raised to
>           the  second.  The second expression must be an integer.
> ```

Ex.

```
$ echo "scale=2; sqrt(2)^2" | bc
1.98
```